# Linked List Javascript, reassignment of variable breaks?

Tags: javascript, linked-list, structure

Can someone explain why these two snippets of code are not equivalent? Why does the first one work whereas the second one does not? I just reassigned the variable name?

```
removeAt(index){
    let count=0;
    if(index > 0 && index >this.size){
        return;
    }
    let current=this.head.next;
    if(index===0){
        this.head.next=this.head.next.next;
    }else{
        let previous;
        while(count<index){
            count++;
            previous=current;
            current=current.next;
        }
        previous.next=current.next;
    }

}
```

However, when I reassign this.head.next to current it does not work????

```
removeAt(index){
    let count=0;
    if(index > 0 && index >this.size){
        return;
    }
    let current=this.head.next;
    if(index===0){
        current=current.next;
    }else{
        let previous;
        while(count<index){
            count++;
            previous=current;
            current=current.next;
        }
        previous.next=current.next;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] including how you call these methods

Comment: I'd argue that neither works. They cannot remove the head itself, and they don't decrement the `.size` when removing.

Comment: "*when I reassign this.head.next to current it does not work?*" - that's just changing the local `current` variable in the function, not the `.next` property of the first node. You can write `this.head.next = current.next` though if you wanted to.